# What are jobject and jmethodID?

Tags: java-native-interface

I wanted to know what **jobect** is? I know it is opaque structure. But how can we access fields of an object using an opaque structure?

When we call a function, using a function pointer (for example GetMethodID), What is ID of a method? how are we we getting the id of a method? What exactly is it's return type. I know it's jmethodID, but what is jmethodID?

Comment: There are six questions here. One at a time here.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

> I wanted to know what jobect is? I know it is opaque structure.

Correct.

> But how can we access fields of an object using an opaque structure?

You can't.

> When we call a function, using a function pointer (for example GetMethodID)

There is no function pointer there, except GetMethodID itself.

> What is ID of a method?

It's an opaque quantum that permanently identifies the method. You don't need to know anything else about it.

> how are we we getting the id of a method?

By calling GetMethodID().

> What exactly is it's return type. I know it's jmethodID, but what is jmethodID?

It's whatever it says it is in jni.h. You don't have any reason for needing any more information than that.